# Does this design have a transitive dependency created by foreign keys, and must a new table be made to put it in 3NF?

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database for a school task, which we've been told must be in 3NF. However, I'm very confused by the concept of transitive dependencies in the case of 3NF too.

Here is an example of a section of my current design:

**Table 1: Customers**

- customer_id (primary key)
- title
- first_name
- last_name
- email
- password
- date_of_birth
- gender
- phone_number
- address_id (references addresses)

**Table 2: Addresses**

- address_id (primary key)
- street_address
- city
- region
- postal_code
- country

**Table 9: Loans**

- loan_id (primary key)
- customer_id (foreign key referencing Customers)
- account_id (foreign key referencing Accounts)
- loan_type (e.g. personal, home, car)
- loan_amount
- loan_term_years
- loan_interest_rate
- request_date
- loan_status (e.g. approved, pending, declined)

After reading through online, I am a bit stumped by the following concept - since the loans table has a foreign key to the customers table (customer_id), but the customers table has a foreign key to the addresses table (address_id), surely this means an address is indirectly accessible via loans table, causing a transitive dependency?

Further to this, I've seen that a potential solution is to create a table called customer_addresses which simply has customer_id and address_id as fields, each being a foreign key. Surely this is also in violation of 3NF where everything should be a primary key, and increases redundancy in my design (which is already huge as is)? What would be an optimal solution to these issues if there are any and how can I ensure that foreign keys aren't causing transitive dependencies across my other tables?